# Why is this getting a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have been trying different functions for validating a hex string, but they all end in a Segmentation Fault. I've researched what that is and it seems to have many reasons that error can pop up.

Here is the function:

```
int validate_hex(const char * hex) {

    if (&hex[strspn(hex, "0123456789abcdefABCDEF")] == 0)
    {
            return 0; //edited: "(null)" is printed in console
    } else {
            return 1; //edited: causes segmentation fault
    }
}
```

And here is the where it is called:

```
int main()
{
    const char input[4096];

    printf("Enter Hexadecimal: ");
    scanf("%s", input);
    //printf("%s\n", &input);

    printf("%d\n", validate_hex(input)); //changing to %d worked Thank you dbush

    return 0;
}
```

Anyone's help explaining what I am not seeing would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Dangerous as all get out directly passing external output into an array without error checking.  Please put that into its own var and check against max size first.

Comment: And of course, compiling with warnings on should catch string/pointer mismatch issues for sure.  Removing the `&` may in front of hex may actually fix your issue, depending on which binds tighter, the & or the []

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings and read the warnings. The compiler is smart enough to point out that, e.g., you're not returning the `int` you promised from `validate_hex`, or that you're trying to pass an `int` where `%s` indicates a `char *` should go. You don't need to bother humans for that.

Comment: Would dereferencing hex with a * instead of '&' help?  Also, you're trying to scan into a constant array, which actually needs to be a char* if you wish to scan in a string of some kind.  Scanning into an initialized char* variable initialized with malloc() for the max string size may be better. It would also seem that you need a pointer to the char* in your declaration of validate_hex if you wish to simulate pass-by-reference (i.e., const char* *).  Then, return the string "invalid" or "valid", don't try to print from the function.

Comment: The address of something can never be NULL,  it's hard to understand why you tried to test this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `validate_hex` returns an `int`, however you're passing it to `printf` with the `%s` format specifier, which expects a `char *` pointing to a null terminated string.

Using the wrong format specifier caused undefined behavior, which in this case manifests as a crash.

Change the format specifier to `%d`, which is used to print an `int`.

```
printf("%d\n", validate_hex(input));
```